# не отображается балун и виснет вкладка на яндекс.карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Беру стандартны, из песочницы код и подключаю его на страницу

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;load=package.full" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/yamap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

yamap.js имеет такой кусок кода:

```
var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
        balloonContentBody: [
            '<address>',
            '<strong>Офис компании</strong>',
            '<br/>',
            'Адрес: г.Москва, Крассная площадь, Кремль',
            '<br/>',
            'Подробнее: <a href="https://msk.ru/">https://msk.ru</a>',
            '</address>'
        ].join('')
    }, {
        preset: 'islands#redDotIcon'
    });
```

Работает нормально.

Но я хочу иметь возможность изменять содержимое контента(ajax или data - не суть)

Ок. Вроде бы тоже не проблема правим код:

```
var company_name = 'Company Ltd.';
var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
        balloonContentBody: [
            '<address>',
            '<strong>',
            company_name,
            '</strong>',
            '<br/>',
            'Адрес: г.Москва, Тессинский переулок д.4',
            '<br/>',
            'Подробнее: <a href="https://rv-1.ru/">https://rv-1.ru</a>',
            '</address>'
        ].join('')
    }, {
        preset: 'islands#redDotIcon'
    });
```

Тоже работает

А вот теперь пусть в company_name появится запятая.

```
var company_name = 'Company1, Company2 Ltd.';
var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
        balloonContentBody: [
            '<address>',
            '<strong>',
            company_name,
            '</strong>',
            '<br/>',
            'Адрес: г.Москва, Тессинский переулок д.4',
            '<br/>',
            'Подробнее: <a href="https://rv-1.ru/">https://rv-1.ru</a>',
            '</address>'
        ].join('')
    }, {
        preset: 'islands#redDotIcon'
    });
```

И всё, балун перестал появляться. Вкладка виснет. В диспетчере видно, что загрузка уходит под 100% по ЦПУ.

Замена на код тоже неэффективна

```
company_name.replace(/\,/g, '&#044;');
```

Если думаете, что замена на обычную строку спасёт - увы:

```
var balloonContent = "<strong>" + company_name + "</strong>  <hr/>" + company_address + "<br/> Подробнее: <a href=\"https://msk.ru/\">https://msk.ru</a>";
var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
        balloonContentBody: balloonContent
    }, {
        preset: 'islands#redDotIcon'
    });
```

Увы, та же фигня, только вид сбоку.

Собственно вопрос: а почему так происходит? Почему в одном случае всё работает нормально, не взирая на запятые, а в остальных наличие запятой приводит к такому пердоманоклю?

Как это преодолеть, обойти?

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести http://jsfiddle.net/dv86xr07/ поправьте пример , предоставленный мной, так, чтобы воспроизводилось.

Comment: Спасибо за пример. Замена <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;load=package.full" type="text/javascript"></script> на <script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script> пофиксила проблему

Comment: Рано радовался. Перенос скрипта на хостинг вызвал ту же проблему. Хотя в тестовой среде всё работает нормально

Comment: Именно поэтому лучше давать ссылку на которой проблема воспроизводится. Вы предоставили только код=)

Comment: ну извините. Я сам не мог подумать на CSS, пока не убрал лишнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно ковыряние в коде оказалось бессмысленным. Причина не в JS, а в LESS/CSS. Мною было добавлено следующее:

```
html{
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    box-sizing: content-box; 
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  }

  i,em,
  b,strong,
  span {
    transition: none;
  }
}
```

Собственно ключ всех проблем здесь

```
transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
```

Не знаю, как это связано непосредственно с YM, но лучше глобально не определять  следующие свойства:

> -webkit-transition
>
> -moz-transition
>
> -o-transition:
>
> -ms-transition transition

Если их убрать - зависания пропадают. Собственно потому что они не определены на  jsfiddle.net там мой код и работал нормально.